# Spark ML Linear Regression - What Hyper-parameters to Tune

Tags: linear-regression, apache-spark-ml, hyperparameters

I'm using the [LinearRegression](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#regression) model in the Spark ML for predicting price. It is a single variate regression `(x=time, y=price)`.

Assume my data is clean, what are the usual steps to take to improve this model?

So far, I tried tuning `regularization parameter` using [cross-validation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#cross-validation), and got `rmse=15` given `stdev=30`.

Are there any other significant hyper-parameters I should care about? It seems Spark ML is not well documented for hyper-parameter tuning...

---

**Update**

I was able to tune up parameters using `ParamGrid` and `Cross-Validation`. However, is there any way to see how the fitted line looks like after correctly training a linear regression model? How can I know if the line is `quadric` or `cubic` etc? It would be great if there is a way to visualize the fitted line with all training data points.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided points to the main hyperparameters:

```
.setRegParam(0.3)   // lambda for regularization
.setElasticNetParam(0.8)  // coefficient for L1 vs L2
```

You can perform a GridSearch to optimize their usage .. say for

```
lambda in 0 to 0.8   
elasticNet in 0 to 1.0
```

This can be done by providing `ParamMap` to `CrossValidator`

```
val estimatorParamMaps: Param[Array[ParamMap]]
param for estimator param maps
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your follow-up question, LinearRegression will also be a linear fit. You can plot it by predicting on a dataset of points across your range for your y-values with a line plot. Then, you can plot your training data on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("PredictiveAnalysis").getOrCreate();

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val data = session.sparkContext.textFile("C:\\Users\\Test\\new_workspace\\PredictionAlgo\\src\\main\\resources\\data.txt");
        val parsedData = data.map { line =>
        val x : Array[String] = line.replace(",", " ").split(" ")
        val y = x.map{ (a => a.toDouble)}
        val d = y.size - 1
                val c = Vectors.dense(y(0),y(d))
                LabeledPoint(y(0), c)
        }.cache();
        val numIterations = 100;
        val stepSize = 0.00000001;
        val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations, stepSize);

        val valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map { point =>
        val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
        (point.label, prediction)
        }

        valuesAndPreds.foreach((result) => println(s"predicted label: ${result._1}, actual label: ${result._2}"))

        val MSE = valuesAndPreds.map{ case(v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2) }.mean()
        println("training Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)
}
```

}

Comment: Please add some details/explanation to your answer, don't dump only code.